# Efficiently create and diff sets created from large text file

Tags: clojure

I am attempting to copy about 12 million documents in an AWS S3 bucket to give them new names. The names previously had a prefix and will now all be document name only. So `a/b/123` once renamed will be `123`. The last segment is a uuid so there will not be any naming collisions.

This process has been partially completed so some have been copied and some still need to be. I have a text file that contains all of the document names. I would like an efficient way to determine which documents have not yet been moved.

I have some naive code that shows what I would like to accomplish.

```
(def doc-names ["o/123" "o/234" "t/543" "t/678" "123" "234" "678"])

(defn still-need-copied [doc-names]
  (let [last-segment  (fn [doc-name] 
                        (last (clojure.string/split doc-name #"/")))
        by-position   (group-by #(.contains % "/") doc-names)
        top           (set (get by-position false))
        nested        (set (map #(last-segment %) (get by-position true)))
        needs-copied  (clojure.set/difference nested top)]
    (filter #(contains? needs-copied (last-segment %)) doc-names)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose this solution:

```
(defn still-need-copied [doc-names]
  (->> doc-names
       (group-by #(last (clojure.string/split % #"/")))
       (keep #(when (== 1 (count (val %))) (first (val %))))))
```

first you group all the items by the last element split string, getting this for your input:

```
{"123" ["o/123" "123"], 
 "234" ["o/234" "234"], 
 "543" ["t/543"], 
 "678" ["t/678" "678"]}
```

and then you just need to select all the values of a map, having length of 1, and to take their first elements.

I would say it is way more readable than your variant, and also seems to be more productive. 
That's why:

as far as I can understand, your code here probably has a complexity of

*N* (grouping to a map with just 2 keys) +

*Nlog(N)* (creation and filling of top set) +

*Nlog(N)* (creation and filling of nested set) +

*Nlog(N)* (sets difference) +

*Nlog(N)* (filtering + searching each element in a needs-copied set) =

```
4Nlog(N) + N
```

whereas my variant would probably have the complexity of

Nlog(N) (grouping values into a map with a large amount of keys) +

N (*keep*ing needed values) =

```
N + Nlog(N)
```

And though asymptotically they are both O(Nlog(N)), practically mine will probably complete faster.

**ps: Not an expert in the complexity theory. Just made some very rough estimation**

here is a little test:

```
(defn generate-data [len]
  (doall (mapcat
           #(let [n (rand-int 2)]
              (if (zero? n)
                [(str "aaa/" %) (str %)]
                [(str %)]))
           (range len))))

(defn still-need-copied [doc-names]
  (let [last-segment  (fn [doc-name] 
                        (last (clojure.string/split doc-name #"/")))
        by-position   (group-by #(.contains % "/") doc-names)
        top           (set (get by-position false))
        nested        (set (map #(last-segment %) (get by-position true)))
        needs-copied  (clojure.set/difference nested top)]
    (filter #(contains? needs-copied (last-segment %)) doc-names)))

(defn still-need-copied-2 [doc-names]
  (->> doc-names
       (group-by #(last (clojure.string/split % #"/")))
       (keep #(when (== 1 (count (val %))) (first (val %))))))

(def data-100k (generate-data 100000))
(def data-1m (generate-data 1000000))

user> (let [_ (time (dorun (still-need-copied data-100k)))
            _ (time (dorun (still-need-copied-2 data-100k)))
            _ (time (dorun (still-need-copied data-1m)))
            _ (time (dorun (still-need-copied-2 data-1m)))])
"Elapsed time: 714.929641 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 243.918466 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 7094.333425 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 2329.75247 msecs"
```

so it is ~3 times faster, just as I predicted

**update:**
found one solution, which is not so elegant, but seems to be working.
You said you're using iota, so i've generated a huge file with the lines of ~15 millions of lines (with forementioned generate-data fn)

then i've decided to sort if by the last part after slash (so that "123" and "aaa/123" stand together.

```
(defn last-part [s] (last (clojure.string/split s #"/")))

(def sorted (sort-by last-part (iota/seq "my/file/path")))
```

it has completed surprisingly fast. So the last thing i had to do, is to make a simple loop checking for every item if there is an item with the same last part nearby:

```
(def res (loop [res [] [item1 & [item2 & rest :as tail] :as coll] sorted]
           (cond (empty? coll) res
                 (empty? tail) (conj res item1)
                 (= (last-part item1) (last-part item2)) (recur res rest)
                 :else (recur (conj res item1) tail))))
```

it has also completed without any visible difficulties, so i've got the needed result without any map/reduce framework.
I think also, that if you won't keep the sorted coll in a var, you would probably save memory by avoiding the huge coll head retention:

```
(def res (loop [res []
                [item1 & [item2 & rest :as tail] :as coll] (sort-by last-part (iota/seq "my/file/path"))]
           (cond (empty? coll) res
           (empty? tail) (conj res item1)
           (= (last-part item1) (last-part item2)) (recur res rest)
           :else (recur (conj res item1) tail))))
```

Comment: I agree your `still-needs-copied` version is much improved compared to the example in my question. However, it is still insufficient. If you bump your `generate-data` to 10,000,000 you will get an error.  I am using  [iota](https://github.com/thebusby/iota) to read the file of 12 million doc names initially. After that I can do some processing using reducers, but I can't manage to accomplish all of the required task with them. It seems an alternative solution is required when working with that may pieces of data.

Comment: yes.. if tweaking jvm memory size doesn't help, maybe you should consider some map/reduce system, like spark for example. https://github.com/gorillalabs/sparkling/ , https://github.com/yieldbot/flambo